# Compiling FFTW (OpenMP) with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, openmp, fftw

I am trying to install FFTW with cmake on my windows machine. I downloaded the  [latest version of the source files](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) and ran cmake with these options first:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake --DBUILD_TESTS=False -DENABLE_FLOAT=On ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

That works just fine on both Visual Studio 2017 and 2019. However, when I tried to compile the code with OpenMP,

```
cmake --DBUILD_TESTS=False -DENABLE_FLOAT=On -DENABLE_OPENMP=On ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

I get a whole bunch of linking errors:

```
[...]
ct.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftwf_ops_zero [C:\Users\jha1\Desktop\fftw-3.3.8.tar\fftw-3.3.8\build\fftw3f_omp.vcxproj]
dft-vrank-geq1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftwf_ops_zero [C:\Users\jha1\Desktop\fftw-3.3.8.tar\fftw-3.3.8\build\fftw3f_omp.vcxproj]
hc2hc.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol fftwf_ops_zero [C:\Users\jha1\Desktop\fftw-3.3.8.tar\fftw-3.3.8\build\fftw3f_omp.vcxproj]
[...]
```

However, it looks like cmake was able to find OpenMP during the configuration phase, so I am not sure what is causing this issue.

```
[...]
-- Found OpenMP_C: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -openmp (found version "2.0")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "2.0")
[...]
```

Note that this worked just fine on my linux machine with gcc 9.

Comment: It is possible that the issue is that  the Microsoft compiler only supports OpenMP 2.0 (which is now 17 years old...), though why that would lead to missing functions at link time is not clear to me. You could install a compiler with support for more modern OpenMP (GCC, LLVM, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to build fftw-3.3.8 in different versions using `configure` in MSYS2 using MinGW-W64 (version from http://winlibs.com) like this:

```
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
BUILDPLATFORM=i686-w64-mingw32
RUNPLATFORM=i686-w64-mingw32
BUILDPLATFORM=x86_64-w64-mingw32
RUNPLATFORM=x86_64-w64-mingw32
mkdir -p build_single build_longdouble build_quad build_standard &&
cd build_single &&
#../configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-portable-binary --enable-sse2 LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
#../configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-single --enable-sse --enable-sse2 --enable-avx LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
../configure --cache-file=../config.cache --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-single --enable-sse --enable-sse2 --enable-avx LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
cd .. &&
cd build_longdouble &&
#../configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-long-double LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
../configure --cache-file=../config.cache --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-long-double LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
cd .. &&
#cd build_quad &&
##../configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-quad-precision LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
#../configure --cache-file=../config.cache --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-quad-precision LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
## fix building DLLs
#mv libtool libtool.bak &&
#sed -e "s/\(allow_undefined=\)yes/\1no/" libtool.bak > libtool &&
#cd .. &&
cd build_standard &&
#../configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-sse2 --enable-avx LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
../configure --cache-file=../config.cache --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --build=$BUILDPLATFORM --host=$RUNPLATFORM --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-alloca --with-our-malloc16 --enable-threads --with-combined-threads --enable-sse2 --enable-avx LDFLAGS="-Wl,--enable-auto-import" &&
cd .. &&
( make -Cbuild_single || make -Cbuild_single LIBS="-lpthread" ) &&
make -Cbuild_single install-strip &&
( make -Cbuild_longdouble || make -Cbuild_longdouble LIBS="-lpthread" ) &&
make -Cbuild_longdouble install-strip &&
#( make -Cbuild_quad || make -Cbuild_quad LIBS="-lpthread" ) &&
#make -Cbuild_quad install-strip &&
( make -Cbuild_standard || make -Cbuild_standard LIBS="-lpthread" ) &&
make -Cbuild_standard install-strip &&
# fix absolute link in .cmake file(s)
sed -i -e "s?$(echo $INSTALLPREFIX|sed -e "s?^/\([a-zA-Z]\)/?\1:/?")?\${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}/../../../..?g" $INSTALLPREFIX/lib/cmake/fftw3/*Config.cmake &&
echo Done
```

If you don't want all these versions you can just stick to the lines relating to `build_standard`.

There were no OpenMP issues building like this.